# Renaming the existing files during MSI installation WIX

Tags: wix, installation, wix3.5, custom-action, wix-extension

I have a WIX Installer and in the installer  i also copy a tutorial project created in VS 2012. What i want is if user has changed the tutorial project by adding new files in it then i just want to rename the existing tutorial and and copy the new tutorail and if user has not changed the existing tutorial then i just want to replace the existing tutorial with the new tutorial.

Is the first question is, Is it really possible using WIX? (Does WIx gives us some functionality like that)

if its possible can some will guide me how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible using the MoveFile element but it's going to be really tricky.  I worked for a company that created a .NET SDK and we build custom project types for VS that allowed the user to say File | New | SomeTypeOfApp  and then use that for training.  We also kept our "tutorial" apps in ZIP files and an application that acted as a front end asking the developer where they would like to extract the sample app to.   This greatly simplified the installer requirements.